# Navbar background wrong color during segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Using iOS 11, Xcode 9, Swift 4

Image below to see what is happening.

The status bar and area just below the largeTitle appear gray during segue until view totally come into view. I have tried setting all of the following in the viewDidLoad and viewWillLoad of the parent and the child views, with no luck:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.detailsTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

[image]

**Question:** How do I make those two gray parts white even during the segue? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You try by using a normal view over your view controller at the place of navigation bar and hide the original navigation bar. You can customise anything in that.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back, thanks.